# Angularjs: How to calculate total price of selected items in array?

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I am new to angularjs. What's wrong with the code below? It does not calculate the total price of all shopped items correctly! :(

I have created an array with items "name", "price" and "isSelected". Total number of checked items is correctly displaying. However it does not calculate the total of their prices correctly. I've tried to use parseInt but it does not seem to help either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1>Select item(s) and add to cart:</h1>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected"></input>
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
<span>{{item.price}}</span>
</label>
</div>
<hr>
<p>Add items to shop</p>
Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="newItemname" />
Enter price: <input type="text" ng-model="newItemprice" />
<button ng-click="addtoshop()">Add to shop</button>
<hr>
<h1>Add items to shopping cart</h1>
<button ng-click="addtocart((items | filter : { isSelected:true }))">Shop!</button>
<hr>
<p ng-model="amount">{{amount}}</p>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.items = [
{name:"Bread", price: 20, isSelected: false},
{name:"Butter", price: 25, isSelected: false},
{name:"Jam", price: 30, isSelected: false},
];
$scope.addtoshop = function(){
var newitem = {};
newitem.name =$scope.newItemname;
newitem.price=$scope.newItemprice; 
$scope.items.push(newitem);
}

$scope.addtocart = function(index){
alert("You chose " + index.length + " items.");
var p=0, i;
for(i=0;i<index.length;i++){
p += parseInt($scope.items[i].price);
}
alert("Shopping price: " + p);
$scope.amount = p;
};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What does p give? Tip: parseInt should always be used with a radix: parseInt($stope.items[i].price, 10). BTW, angular@1.0.7 is 2 years old!

Comment: total price of selected items.

Comment: So p is calculated correctly?

Comment: No, if i select Bread + Jam it shows 45

Comment: You are only iterating over the list of items, not over the list of selected items, so it will calculate Bread+Butter in any case. You need to add the items which are selected only.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you mix 2 collections on the iteration in `addtocart` method.

Here a fix

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1>Select item(s) and add to cart:</h1>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected"></input>
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
<span>{{item.price}}</span>
</label>
</div>
<hr>
<p>Add items to shop</p>
Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="newItemname" />
Enter price: <input type="text" ng-model="newItemprice" />
<button ng-click="addtoshop()">Add to shop</button>
<hr>
<h1>Add items to shopping cart</h1>
<button ng-click="addtocart((items | filter : { isSelected:true }))">Shop!</button>
<hr>
<p ng-model="amount">{{amount}}</p>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.items = [
{name:"Bread", price: 20, isSelected: false},
{name:"Butter", price: 25, isSelected: false},
{name:"Jam", price: 30, isSelected: false},
];
$scope.addtoshop = function(){
var newitem = {};
newitem.name =$scope.newItemname;
newitem.price=$scope.newItemprice; 
$scope.items.push(newitem);
}

$scope.addtocart = function(cartItems){
alert("You chose " + cartItems.length + " items.");
var p=0, i;
for(i=0;i<cartItems.length;i++){
p += parseInt(cartItems[i].price);
}
alert("Shopping price: " + p);
$scope.amount = p;
};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```